# Using SetupTools on Google App Engine to dynamically download and install python modules

Tags: python, google-app-engine, setuptools, python-2.7

I would like to build an admin section into my App Engine app that will allow me to download and install python modules dynamically.

Any ideas on the most efficient way to accomplish this, without the ability to write to file system?

Are there any examples of this being done?

Does [python27 support of setuptools](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27.html#setuptools) make this easier?

**Edit:**

My initial thought is that this could be accomplished by downloading an egg or zip file dynamically. Saving it to the blobstore, and loading if from there.

Is this posible?

What kind of performance issues would this create?

Comment: ...why on earth would you want to do this?

Comment: @NickJohnson Easy of use, primarily. I'm building an e-commerce app and I would like to give developers the ability to load plugins and download patches thru an admin section instead of requiring a redeploy. Any hint on how this could be accomplished? imp module?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest against doing it. Let them redeploy (or redeploy it yourself if you're doing SAAS), or build in the full set of extensions and let them enable them as required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On GAE you has no access to the file system, that's why you can't install any third-party packages on your instance, you can only distribute they with your own code.

Comment: I realize this. I was thinking that maybe this limitation could be circumvented by loading a module as a zip file or an egg from the blobstore.

Comment: Nope. There zipped module would have to be available to the app as a resource. The only way to upload resources is via `appcfg` (or something that front-ends it).

Comment: Actually, you certainly could write a custom import hook that imports Python modules from an arbitrary source. But I can't figure out why you'd want to.

Answer (score 1):

In your app directory create a folder called 'lib'. For any module you want to add, just unzip it and add it to lib. Then redeploy your application using the console or Google App Launcher. Repeat every time you want to add a new module.

I'm not 100% sure about this. But it seems to me that if don't want a manual process involved then I would suggest dynamically adding the module content as a blob store entry and loading the module at runtime.

But the trick as the previous answer states is that to use a package, its code needs to be present in your app.

Comment: Loading from the blob store is what I would like to do. Do you have any thoughts on how to load the module at runtime? Thanks